# Image file URI vs Image Bitmap

Tags: android-image, google-mlkit

I'm using ML Kit to label images with a custom model on Android. Which `InputImage` is better to pass into the model that can provide more accurate results? Bitmap or image file URI?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference in results accuracies between those 2 if image is converted correctly to bitmap. However, if you need to use bitmap in your app anyhow, passing bitmap to MLKit will make the latency smaller as creating MLKit InputImage from file path convert it to a bitmap internally.